# Merge values of two rows to create a new row

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like below:

[image]

This is one example of what we want the end result to look like:

[image]

I have tried solutions in these links

1. [Combine column from multiple rows into single row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17921/combine-column-from-multiple-rows-into-single-row)
2. [Merge or Combine Multiple Rows Records to Single Column Record with
   Comma delimiters](http://raresql.com/tag/merge-or-combine-multiple-rows-records-to-single-column-record-with-comma-delimiters/)
3. [Rolling up multiple rows into a single row and column for SQL
   Server data](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2914/rolling-up-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-and-column-for-sql-server-data/)
4. [How to combine values from multiple rows of a single column (T-SQL,
   Microsoft SQL Server, FOR XML PATH, CSV ). - See more at:
   http://carlosferreira.com/how-to-combine-values-from-multiple-rows-of-a-single-column-t-sql-microsoft-sql-server-for-xml-path-csv/#sthash.GFGO956K.dpuf](http://carlosferreira.com/how-to-combine-values-from-multiple-rows-of-a-single-column-t-sql-microsoft-sql-server-for-xml-path-csv/)

but all of theme combine rows in just one column and seperate values with a seperator, however i want to take the value of first row in Input column and the second row in Output column as shown above.

Comment: How we can find `A1` in input and `A2` is Output. Why not vice versa

Comment: @Indian, I have said that in last part of my question: "i want to take the value of first row in Input column and the second row in Output column"

Comment: That's what am asking you how to find that `order` of rows do you have any other column to find the `order`

Comment: @Indian, No, the order of rows is by the order of inserting theme.

Comment: @M_Mogharrabi Do you have `identity / Datetime` column atleast else you cannot find the order of insertion

Comment: @M_Mogharrabi I've updated my answer to `order by id` instead of `order by destination`. this is more reliable, please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below query:
I am using `PIVOT` with `ROW_NUMBER OVER` to generate Input/Output values separately from rows. Note that any business logic for determining Input/output goes in the inner query creating table `s`

```
select id,name, [1] as input, [2] as [Output] from 
(select id,name,destination,row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as colnum from tbl) s
pivot
(
 max(destination) for colnum in ([1],[2])
)p
```

Sample sql fiddle link here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ed9f2/2

Comment: What will be the answer of first row is `A2` and second row is `A11`. You input and output will not be in order

Comment: Doesn't change anything - ID is the same for both rows. Unless there's some reliable criteria for sorting (such as a column containing the insertion timestamp) the "order" of records with the same ID may still be arbitrary.